# Linq Sql Query using Starts With lat/long

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a Latitude Column in the db that has values that look like this `41.230524` , using HTML5 geolocation I get a more accurate Latitude that will look like this `41.230524081`

I want to find the row in my  db  that is closest to the Latitude returned from Geolocation.  I was thinking something like

```
var myCity = db.zipcodes.Where(x => LatFromGeoCode.StartsWith(x.Latitude)).FirstOrDefault();
```

the problem with that is there may be different cities in the db that start with 41.2XXXXX , I don't just want the first one  , I want the closest match

I was thinking maybe a loop first trying to match the full LatFromGeo, then -1 char , then try again , it seems there must be a better way

Comment: Is `41.3` closer to `41.295524081` than `41.2`?

Comment: 41.3 is ok compared to 41.290 , but not compared to 41.20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the one with the smallest mathematical difference:

```
double minDiff = db.zipcodes.Min(x => Math.Abs(x.Latitude - LatFromGeoCode));
var myCity = db.zipcodes.Where(x => Math.Abs(x.Latitude - LatFromGeoCode) == minDiff).FirstOrDefault();
```

(There is a way better way to do this with compression syntax, but I don't know linq to sql well enough to write it out quickly)

Here's the SQL if someone wants to convert it:

```
SELECT TOP 1 zipcode
FROM zipcodes z
WHERE ABS(z.Latitude - @LatFromGeoCode) = MIN(ABS(z.Latitude - @LatFromGeoCode))
```

Comment: that looks very good way , but also looks very slow ,  i'll give it a shot - i'll se what linq pad turns this into

Comment: this math has a very big problem - it will only work given the coordinates are in the north!! Once you add results from the southern half of earth, the Lat will be negative !! which means that the results will be mixed, and you might get two locations with the same min value.

Comment: @Segev-CJ-Shmueli True, but it's easy to tweak the math to make it work. This should be done using a difference of some kind.

Comment: must add another condition to check the +/- state, and then you can use ABS method. Yes it will make it even sluggisher (is that a word?), but it's necessary .